# Adicionar código analytics em blog Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-api

Estou tentando mudar o código **Analytics** de um blog em Wordpress. Porém, não possuo muito conhecimento e estou tendo dificuldades de descobrir como o código foi adicionado.

Pelo que eu pesquise, consegui descobrir 3 formas de adicionar o código analytics no wordpress. Porém, nenhuma dessas formas foi utilizada e mesmo assim ele possui um código analytics ja adicionado.

**As formas que eu encontrei são:**

- Usando um plugin (Olhei nos plugins e não encontrei o **Google Analytics** ou qualquer outro plugin com a palavra **"Analytics"**).
- Inserindo o código no `header.php` do tema (O tema não possui o script da tag do analytcs. Mas possui uma função PHP que talvez adicione algo: `<?php wp_head(); ?>` Porém, não sei ao certo se o código é inserido por esta função).
- Criando uma nova função no arquivo `functions.php` (Procurei neste arquivo e ele também não possui nenhum script para o analytics)

Essas foram as únicas formas que encontrei de adicionar código Analytics em Wordpress. Mas pelo que parece, o código foi adicionado de outra forma.

**Existem outras formas para adicionar o código do Analytics no Wordpress?**

Comment: Seu tema tem algum plugin que se chama Yoast ?

Comment: Sim @hugocsl. Tem o plugin "Yoast SEO Premium".

Comment: Esse site está publicado tem link? O script do Google que vc está encontrando está no topo ou no fím da página ?

Comment: Sim. Está publicado! o código aparece no head das páginas. Ele parece ser adicionado pela função "wp_head()" do arquivo header.php.

Comment: Cara vai no tema, na parte de Aparência > Editar > Procura o header.php deve estar dentro dele

Comment: Não está. Como eu disse lá em cima. No header.php do Tema, tenho apenas a função wp_head(). Eu inclusive adicionei o novo código do analytics la e o meu aparece logo abaixo do antigo na página. Deixando ela com dois códigos do analytics. Acima da tag de script que eu adicionei não existe nenhuma tag de script. tudo é adicionado em execução. Por isso acredito que seja essa função "wp_head()".

Comment: pode ser o YOAST, desabilite ele e veja se analytics permanece: 
Yoast Plugin > Features > Disabled e salve as mudanças

Comment: Eu não tenho muito conhecimento em wordpress. Então não me sinto seguro em desabilitar esse plugin. Porque ele pode estar fazendo outras configurações. Vou pesquisar e estudar um pouco mais sobre ele antes. Para não afetar o funcionamento do blog.

Comment: Tente pela força bruta: baixe todos os arquivos numa pasta e faça uma busca pelo Windows procurando pelo termo "analytics" dentro dos arquivos.

Comment: @dvd o mais engraçado é que fiz isso e por incrível que pareça, não está nos arquivos. O código do analytics antigo só aparece nas paginas HTML de cache do blog. O que me faz acreditar fortemente que essa configuração venha de algum plugin!

Comment: Se tivesse como ir desabilitando cada plugin de uma vez e verificando.

Comment: @dvd eu pretendo fazer isso, mas com calma. Como eu não tenho muito conhecimento em Wordpress, pretendo estudar um pouco sobre cada plugin antes de desabilitar. Para saber bem o efeito disso no blog. Eu ja adicionei o novo código, então ele pelo menos ja está sendo rastreado. Meu problema agora é que ele tem dois códigos analytics. O antigo e o novo, então eu preciso remover o antigo e deixar apenas o novo.

Comment: Entendi, mas o que eu quis dizer era vc desabilitar (mesmo que afete o blog) um plugin, dar refresh no blog e ver se o analytics antigo sumiu; se não, habilita o plugin novamente e parte pro outro fazendo a mesma coisa.

Comment: @alan Se você utiliza um servidor linux, acesse a raiz do seu projeto e execute o seguinte comando: ` grep -irwn "analytic*" --include "*.php"`. Assim ele vai listar todos os arquivos que contém essa palavra. Outra alternativa é buscar no banco de dados o código do Analytics, dessa forma você poderá exclui-lo; Caso ainda sim não resolva, provavelmente ele está encriptado e será necessário verificar plugin por plugin.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr obrigado. Mas eu fiz o processo de verificação (busca) em todos os arquivos do blog no sublime text. Então acredito fortemente que essa configuração está vindo de algum plugin. Testarei cada um deles com calma e quando encontrar postarei aqui o que era!

Comment: Fiz muita pesquisa em relação ao seu problema, e em quase todo lugar a dica é a mesma: desabilitar os plugins e ir habilitando um por um (dando refresh antes no blog) para ver se aparece o analytics antigo. Ao habilitar um plugin novamente e aparecer o analytics, vc irá saber que é ele que está gerando. Mas isso tem que ser um processo rápido, mesmo que o Blog se desconfigure por alguns instantes, creio que não seja grande problema para vc achar de onde vem isso.

Comment: @dvd obrigado pelo empenho em tentar me ajudar. Mas para minha surpresa a configuração estava dentro da tela de configuração do próprio tema! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente consegui achar. Graças a ajuda de vocês. Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar com dicas nos comentários **:D**

Antes estava sempre acessando *Aparência -> Editor*, selecionando o tema atual e procurando o código nos arquivos `header.php`, `functions.php` e nos demais.

Porém dessa vez fui em `Aparência -> Temas`. Foram listados todos os temas. Cliquei em *Personalizar* do tema que estou utilizando. Uma nova tela de edição carregou com um menu lateral. Cliquei na opção *Theme Panel* do menu. Após isso, outra página de configuração foi aberta **"Newspaper - Theme panel"** exibindo o menu do painel do próprio wordpress e outro menu do tema ao lado. Então cliquei no menu *ANALYTICS* do tema. E uma caixa com o código analytics foi aberta! :)

**Caminho completo:** Aparência -> Temas -> Personalizar -> Theme Panel -> ANALYTICS

Answer (score -3):

Entra no **header.php** ou no **footer.php** do seu **TEMA** e adicione o código Fornecido pelo Google.

Exemplo de um codigo do Google:

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-114669691-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-ID-1');
    </script>
```

```
No header.php coloque antes de </head>
No footer.php coloque antes do </body>
```

Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Exemplo</title>

    <!-- Faça dessa forma se for usar no header.php -->

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-114669691-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-ID-1');
    </script> <!-- Faça dessa forma se for usar no header.php -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Olá Mundo!</h1>

    <!-- Faça dessa forma se for usar no footer.php -->
    
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-114669691-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-ID-1');
    </script> <!-- Faça dessa forma se for usar no footer.php -->
  </body>
</html>
```